# The site works differently on iOS, how to fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ios

I have a problem with iOS, when the middle element is full on iOS, it grows down, but on other devices it grows up. I would like to know how to fix it so it works like on other devices. In the example div with outputText class, when it fills up the parent on iOS it appears lower and should go up like on other devices.

```js
const output = document.getElementById("output");
const addbtn = document.getElementById("addcontext");
const addtext = textToAdd => {
  output.innerHTML += `<div class="outputText">${textToAdd}</div>`;
};
let i = 0;
addbtn.addEventListener("click", function () {
  
  addtext("example text " + i);
  i++;
});
```

```css
#module {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0 !important;
  left: 0 !important;
  bottom: 0 !important;
  width: 100% !important;
  height: 100% !important;
  display: flex;
  top: 0 !important;
  flex-direction: column;
  border-radius: 0;
  overflow-x: auto;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  min-width: 360px;
}

#head {
  display: block !important;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 4;
}

#headelem {
  display: flex !important;
  align-items: center;
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  min-height: 36px;
  border-radius: 5px 5px 0 0;
  filter: drop-shadow(0px 4px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1));
  border-bottom: 4px solid lightgrey;
  border-top: 0;
  border-left: 0;
  border-right: 0;
}

#con-middle {
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#middle {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  min-height: 0;
  width: auto !important;
  z-index: 3;
  height: 100%;
}

#foot {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 3;
  display: block !important;
  background: lightblue;
}

#content {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex-direction: column-reverse;
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  border-radius: 1px;
}

#have-content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#output {
  width: calc(100%);
  max-height: none !important;
  min-height: 0 !important;
  position: relative;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.outputText {
  margin: 20px 10px;
}

#addcontext {
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="module">
    <div id="head">
      <div id="headelem">some text</div>
    </div>
    <div id="con-middle">
      <div id="middle">
        <div id="content">
          <div id="have-output">
            <div id="output"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div id="foot">
        <button id="addcontext"> add context</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: If you only have one parameter, arrow functions don't need parenthesis. This: `const addtext = (textToAdd) => {` can change to this: `const addtext = textToAdd => {`

Comment: Thanks, I know that, but I'm in the habit of inserting these and I can't get rid of it :P

Comment: I can't test it but try to remove `max-height` and `min-height` from `#output` in css and test to see if that changes anything on IOS

Comment: @KresimirPendic nothing change